# Removing an dynamically and previously added event listener on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, addeventlistener, dom-events, event-listener

In C#  I have executed JavaScript by `ExecuteScript()` function. In JavaScript I have added an EventListener to webpage by clicking an button say 'Attach'. Now I want to remove that EventListener on another button click say 'Detach'.

Now under 'Attach' button Form.
I have written following:

```
document.addEventListener('click', hilightElement, false);
```

where `highlightElement` is my function.

Under 'Detach' button Form.
I have written following

```
document.removeEventListener('click', hilightElement);
```

here document.removeEventListener does not work i.e the EventListener which i added still exist.

Is  there any way that I can remove the event listener so that 'click' event does not do anything after 'Detach' button click.

Comment: The code you've shown works fine in an all Javascript environment so there must be something about your specific implementation that makes it not work.  You will probably have to show us more of the implementation for us to know where it's going wrong.

Comment: exactly what is problem be specific?

Comment: There is possibility of multiple `event-listeners` on same element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code as below, and it works as expected:

```js
var attach = document.getElementById('attach');
var detach = document.getElementById('detach');
var hilightElement = function() {
  alert("Here");
};
attach.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.addEventListener('click', hilightElement, false);
});
detach.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.removeEventListener('click', hilightElement);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="attach">Attach</button>
<button type="button" id="detach">Detach</button>
```

Comment: Hi Rayon, thanks for your answer. But i am working on C# context so i cannot use detach.addEventListener as it is id of you Html Button. Can you help me in C# context where Attach and Detach are my 2 forms showed in button form. and on click of those AddEvent and RemoveEvent should happen respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try Rayons example, since I realized I was writing the same code.

Comment: This works fine, but addEventListener is on different button click and removeEventListener is on different button click. Please try that

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It doesn't matter which function adds and removes the handler as long as both have access to the handler variable.

Comment: This method may not be cross browser safe. Firefox does not appear to return anything from addEventListener. @Shilly

Comment: @Shilly I tried the way you told. But with this way the EventListener is getting Added one more time instead of removing. Please help

Comment: The first line goes into the attach function, the second line goes into the detach function? And you obv want to attach the handler to the button, not the document. I'll update my code to spoonfeed.